# How to have JAWS read something different from what is displayed on screen

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have this part of code:

```
<div role="heading" aria-level="5" >
     <span role="text" aria-label="This is another title example">Title example</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that I want that JAWS reads the text of the aria label 'This is another title example' but in the list of heading, I want to see only the span text 'Title example'.

I use the `role="text"` and this is work fine in Chrome, but not in IE.
Is there a correct structure to have my request (in the list of headings I would like to see only the text 'Title example' but when I navigate with JAWS, the heading pronunciation must be aria-label 'This is another title example') in Chrome and IE?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to hide the actual text from JAWS?

Comment: I'm wondering why you're not using `<h5>` instead of dressing up a `div`.

Comment: @isherwood : I want a structure html that works fine in chrome and IE . The code above works fine only in Chrome.

Comment: @heretic monkey: I could use <h5> but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: That doesn't help me understand what "works fine" means.

Comment: I want that jaws pronunce the aria-label when I'm on heading, but in the jaws list of heading (that appears with insert + f6), I want to see the text of heading. The code above works fine in chrome but not in IE

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question, I will explain what you do and where are the errors.

1. An ARIA-LABEL overrides the actual text of an element. In your example, the value of the ARIA-LABEL replaces the 'Title example'.
2. If you want to display specific content to the screen reader user, you should use the common technique called 'screen reader only text'.

```
<div role="heading" aria-level="5" >
<span class="sr-only">This is another </span><span role="text">Title example</span>
</div>
```

3. With JAWS, the list of heading will consider the hidden content so you'll see 'This is another title example'
4. "If you can use a native HTML element or attribute with the semantics and behavior you require already built-in, instead of re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property to make it accessible, then do so". This is the first rule of [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1). You should remove all unnecessary ARIA attributes.

- element has implicitly a role=heading and an aria-level=5
- with a role=text is useless because the content inside the h5 tags is consider has text

```
<h5>
<span class="sr-only">This is another </span>Title example     
</h5>
```